# Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]

Tags: spring, hibernate

I encounter below exception, can someone help?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.stixcloud.config.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.stixcloud.main.StixCloneProductMain.main(StixCloneProductMain.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp.run(WrapperJarApp.java:427)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.stixcloud.config.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.stixcloud.config.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolv
```

below are the config class, we are using spring, hibernate, java wrapper

```
package com.stixcloud.config.persistence;

import com.stixcloud.service.common.factory.SisticCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
import com.stixcloud.service.common.factory.SisticMultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import com.stixcloud.service.common.listener.AuditInterceptor;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurer;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true, mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@PropertySource(value = "file:/opt/appsconfig/database.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class PersistenceConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PersistenceConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${tenant.list}")
    private String tenantList;

    public DataSource newDataSource(String jdbcUrl, String jdbcUser, String jdbcPassword) {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setURL(jdbcUrl);
            dataSource.setUser(jdbcUser);
            dataSource.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error to create common datasource " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SisticMultiTenantConnectionProvider sisticMultiTenantConnectionProvider() {
        logger.info("Initializing datasource...");
        SisticMultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new SisticMultiTenantConnectionProvider();
        Map<String, DataSource> map = new HashMap<String, DataSource>();
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(tenantList)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No tenants configured in tenant list. Please check jdbc.properties.");
        }
        String[] tenants = tenantList.split(",");
        for(String tenantID : tenants) {
            String tenantJdbcUrl = environment.getProperty(tenantID + ".jdbc.url");
            String tenantJdbcUser = environment.getProperty(tenantID + ".jdbc.user");
            String tenantJdbcPassword = environment.getProperty(tenantID + ".jdbc.password");
            DataSource dataSource = this.newDataSource(tenantJdbcUrl, tenantJdbcUser, tenantJdbcPassword);
            map.put(tenantID.toUpperCase(), dataSource);
            logger.info("Datasource initialized for tenant code " + tenantID.toUpperCase());
        }
        connectionProvider.setMap(map);
        logger.info("Datasource initialization completed.");
        return connectionProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SisticCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
        return new SisticCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditInterceptor auditInterceptor() {
        return new AuditInterceptor();
    }

    /**
     * Session factory.
     * 
     * @return the local session factory bean
     * @throws IOException
     *             Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.stixcloud.domain");
        sessionFactory.setEntityInterceptor(this.auditInterceptor());

        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", this.sisticMultiTenantConnectionProvider());
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.multiTenancy", "DATABASE");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", this.currentTenantIdentifierResolver());
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.dialect", "com.stixcloud.common.dialect.OracleNativeDialect");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "50");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "false");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer", "true");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob", "true");
        sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "0");

        try {
            sessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error to create session factory " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "hbTxManager")
    @DependsOn("sessionFactory")
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(this.sessionFactory());
        hibernateTransactionManager.setAutodetectDataSource(false);
        return hibernateTransactionManager;
    }

    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return this.hibernateTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

sorry i saw another stack trace, while run again, this is the most bottom stack trace, which should be the cause

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getAnyConnection(AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$MultiTenantConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at com.stixcloud.config.persistence.PersistenceConfig.sessionFactory(PersistenceConfig.java:111)
    at com.stixcloud.config.persistence.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$141223b.CGLIB$sessionFactory$4()
    at com.stixcloud.config.persistence.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$141223b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9f56ffc0.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at com.stixcloud.config.persistence.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$141223b.sessionFactory()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: share your configuration class and also brief about your tech stack

Comment: hi @YogendraR , just updated config class as above, we are using spring, hibernate, java wrapper

Comment: can you try removing sessionFactory.getObject(), just return sessionFactory and while calling setSessionFactory() use sessionFactory().getObject() and also annotate your   newDataSource() with @Bean

Comment: i tried, but still same exception.

Comment: return sessionFactory.getObject() changed to return (SessionFactory) sessionFactory. hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(this.sessionFactory()) changed to hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(((LocalSessionFactoryBean) sessionFactory()).getObject()). and annotated newDataSource() with @Bean too

Comment: hi, i updated above, i saw another stack trace, while run again, this is the most bottom stack trace, which should be the cause... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getAnyConnection(AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:42)

Answer (score 0):

In your hibernate configuration class file you should properly define your session object attributes an its dialect, datasource and transaction manager, don't forget to annotate them with @Bean

Comment: i did all that, how do u propose to change the above codes?

Comment: hi, i updated above, i saw another stack trace, while run again, this is the most bottom stack trace, which should be the cause... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getAnyConnection(AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:42)

Comment: I think it will helping if you share your configuration class code and code that throws the exception